Expand Pandas Dataframe, using combination of different list columns (that don't have the same amount of values)
I am working on a pandas dataframe where I would like to get a list of when all different datasets are refreshing.
The problem is that the data is in two parts. One column contains a list of all the days it is scheduled to refresh. The other column contains a list of all the times it is scheduled to refresh.
For example
data = {
    "id": ["a", "b", "c","d"],
    "refresh_days": [["Monday", "Friday"], [], [], ["Sunday"]],
    "refresh_time": [["01:00"], [], [], ["03:00", "06:00"]],
}

I tried using the explode method, but that requires you to have the same amount of elements between both.
The output I would like to get is a pandas Dataframe



ID
Result




a
monday 1:00


a
friday 1:00


b
Nan


c
Nan


d
Sunday 3:00


d
Sunday 6:00




Explode one at a time. This will give you the results you are expecting:
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = df.explode('refresh_days').explode('refresh_time')
df['Result'] = df['refresh_days'] + " " + df['refresh_time']
df = df.drop(columns=['refresh_days', 'refresh_time'])
df


Beat me to it, +1 :) Note: You can do df["Result"] = df.pop("refresh_days") + " " + df.pop("refresh_time") to save a line.

Clever use of pop...you seniors and your cleverness haha
